# Merge over several columns of a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have two datatables, the first main one has columns like this

```
Name ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4 ID5 ID6 ID7 ID8
```

the second "lookup" data table looks like

```
ID Value
```

I want to merge those two tables by going through each of the ID columns in the main table, and if it matches the ID of the lookup table, it should take the value from the lookup table.

I tried the following: 
First, setting keyvariables

```
setkeyv(maintable, "ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID5", "ID6", "ID7" , "ID8")
setkeyv(lookuptable, "ID")
```

and then

```
maintable[lookuptable, Dummy:=Value]
```

This works, but just for the first ID1, not for all the other 7 ones. I assume there is a clever data.table way to perform this, can somebody help me out?

Comment: Convert the first dataset to long format (`melt()`) so that you have only one ID and one Name column and then use a simple join

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot! Though going wide -> long and then back long-> wide is not really super convenient, but whatever works.